# boost asio async_tcp_echo_server example

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I'm looking at this example from boost site (for learning purposes):

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

In main I added few threads to run io_context.

The behavior I achieved is that I have multiple threads listen on the socket, each waits for work and does the whole work a-z, so if all my threads are busy doing work and another client sends some text to the server he'll hang until some thread will be available again.

I want 1 thread to listen on a socket and queue all the work and a thread pool to handle all the work.

If I understand right I don't need to create a thread pool in main but leave it as is with only main thread to accept connections and make another io_context with a thread pool in the server and somehow make all the sessions use this pool, I can't figure out how to write this.

I also still don't understand how each session knows which io_context it uses if I don't pass it to the session.

Answer (score 1):

The socket stores an executor. That executor refers to the `io_context`.

In older Boost versions, sockets would store a reference to an `io_service` directly.

Comment: Where did they pass the io_context (executor) to the socket? Can I change it to another io_context ?

Comment: You can post work on a different executor. The idea is to work with your handler types to [imply the associated executor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/get_associated_executor.html). A prime example of this is when using strands. The design is intricate, but very very potent and flexible. I love this page as a full-depth documentation of how it all hangs together: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/writing_composed_operations.html